# "Interface HD" Needs to be Updated

Tags: ios, interface

I am developing in Objective-C for iPad.  I'm using X-Code V12.5.1. My development target is V12.1. I'm using an iPad Air 4th Gen for testing.
I recently updated the iPad to 14.7.1 and when I ran the App from X-Code to the iPad, after a few minutes it came up with the message ""Interface HD" Needs to be Updated" The developer of this app needs to update it to work with this version of iPadOS".
I have searched on what this message means but can't find anything. I can't even find what is the "Interface HD". Can someone please help?
[image: Interface HD Screen shot]

Comment: It is the name of some app on your device that doesn't have 64 bit support

Comment: Awesome, thanks Paul.  Can you suggest a how I can determine what components would be causing this?  The only add-in I'm using is Google Firebase, is that likely to be the culprit?  Both FirebaseCore and GoogleUtilities do throw up Buildtime issues.

Comment: Is your app called "Interface HD"?

Comment: Ha, thank you for that. I just realised it's not talking about my App.  My App is called Simple Meeting Minutes.  I have another App installed that I haven't used for ages called "Interface HD". It was just coincidental that the message popped up while I was testing SMM.  I'll delete that App and I thing I'll be all good.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: yes, just tap "Delete" and move on :)

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't my App, was another App that doesn't support 64 bit OS.  Thanks Paulw11 for your help.  Deleted offending App.